# CloudWatch logs querying - dedup with count?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have the following log query:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /some-message/ and @message like /"level":"info"/
| dedup katalLogger.httpData.amzMonsCustomer.0
```

This often gives me more than 10K results which exceeds the max limit i can set for the `limit` param.

Is there any way i could get the `count` of that query?